# Onedrive for business initial synch

Tags: sync, onedrive

We are evaluating onedrive for business.  We have 16 users with 25 Gb of data that is currently synched via a Lan synch software.

We want to move it to the cloud, but one problem is the upload/download time.  We will set up one admin account, upload the 25GB of files, then share to all staff who would also have one drive accounts as part of the business account

As all users already have all the 25 Gb of files on their PC's is there any way we can avoid that every user has to download files from Onedrive?

Answer (score 0):

No would be the short answer. OneDrive is quite temperamental even with a small number/size of files and even day to day operation can easily cause it to become out of sync with the server, a problem that frequently occurs and whose only solution, according to Microsoft ([http://community.office365.com/en-us/f/148/t/249087.aspx](http://community.office365.com/en-us/f/148/t/250278.aspx)) & (http://community.office365.com/en-us/f/148/t/250278.aspx) just to list two examples, is to manually or automatically "repair" the drive (which means you or OneDrive moves all your client side files into an archive folder and redownloads everything). This process takes a very long period of time and can't be done if others are using the system. My advice would be to look into Google Drive, which our company used for several years with no issues whatsoever until we made the ill-fated move to SkyDrive.

Comment: I noticed the same behavior regarding re-downloading files. DropBox is better with syncing. Files are analyzed to create a hash and those values are compared. If they are different, then that's when the sync occurs. DropBox also has LAN sync so you avoid having to redownload 25GB of documents to each workstation. OneDrive is good if you're backing up a lot of Office documents, but definitely poor in terms of optimum transfer of data.